# Live stream IP Camera (CCTV) In ASGI Server Issue

Tags: python, django, opencv, daphne, asgi

I'm using django, opencv, daphne, asgi for my system. Using wsgi able to live stream cctv in html without any issue. When using asgi unable live stream cctv in html.
Going through alot example in web and found out, current status able to use websocket to open the html but still unable show live stream for cctv.
Any suggestion/recommendation what I can do next? I had out of ideas.

consumer.py

```
class CameraConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:ads12345@192.168.1.65:554/")

        while True:
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            if not ret:
                print("Unable read video")
                break

            _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame_bytes = buffer.tobytes()

            await asyncio.sleep(0.03)
            await self.send(json.dumps({'frame':frame_bytes.decode('latin-1')}))

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        self.cap.release()
```

routing.py

```
ws_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/camera_stream/', CameraConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

stream.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Camera Stream</title>
    <script>
        var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws/camera_stream/");

        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
            var img = document.getElementById("camera-image");
            img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + event.data;
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="camera-image" src="" >
</body>
</html>
```

wsgi able use streaminghttpresponse to live stream but asgi use the same is not working.